# Remove duplicates from a list in SML

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I just started learning functional programming in SML and I want to know how I can combine the following two functions into a single function. The function isolate deletes the duplicates of a list of any type ('a) using the helper function 'removes'.

```
fun isolate [] = []
  | isolate (l as x::xs) = x::isolate(remove(x,xs))

fun remove (x,[]) = []
  | remove (x,l as y::ys) = if x = y then remove(x,ys) else y::remove(x,ys)
```

So, for the purpose of better understanding the constructs in the SML, how would you include the function remove within isolate? This may seem trivial, but I have thinking about it and can't figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One method would be to just define `remove` inside `isolate`.

```
fun isolate [] = []
  | isolate (l as x::xs) =
      let fun remove (x,[]) = []
            | remove (x,l as y::ys) = if x = y
                                      then remove(x,ys)
                                      else y::remove(x,ys)
      in
        x::isolate(remove(x,xs))
      end
```

Alternately, to make deduplication one function, though all this really does is use the library function `List.filter` to do the same thing that `remove` does.

```
fun isolate [] = []
  | isolate (x::xs) = x::isolate(List.filter (fn y => y <> x) xs)
```

Comment: Hey @qaphla, when I compile your code I'm getting an operator and operand don't agree error, I can't find the error.

Comment: never mind. I found it when you call the remove method in the 'in' part of the let. You are not passing the correct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

My idea: define a nested function to check if there are duplicated elements in the list:

```
fun set(nums:int list)=
  let fun duplicate(x:int, l:int list)=
    if null l
    then false
    else hd l=x orelse duplicate(x,tl l)
  in
      if null nums
      then []
      else
      let val s=set(tl nums)
      in if duplicate(hd nums,s)
         then s
         else hd nums::s
      end
  end
```

But it will give a list that only remains the last one for every duplicated elements.

Answer (score 0):

I want to propound the following solutions of this problem:

```
fun remove_duplicates(xs: int list) = 
    let
        fun check(xs: int list, item: int) =
            if null xs
            then false
            else if hd xs = item
            then true
            else check (tl xs, item)
        fun go_through_list(xs: int list) =
            if null xs
            then []
            else if check(tl xs, hd xs)
                 then go_through_list(tl xs)
                 else hd xs :: go_through_list(tl xs)
    in
        go_through_list(xs)
    end
```

It's more lines of code than in the solution propounded by @qaphla

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to first sort the list, then recursively return a new list without duplicates:

```
fun remove_duplicates(l: int list) =
if null(l)
then []
else if null(tl l)
then l
else
    let
        fun compare(x: int, y: int) = x > y
        fun sort(l: int list) = ListMergeSort.sort(compare) l
        val l_sorted = sort(l)
    in
        if (hd l_sorted) = (hd (tl l_sorted))
        then remove_duplicates(tl l_sorted)
        else (hd l_sorted)::remove_duplicates(tl l_sorted)
    end
```